# How to run redux devtools with redux saga?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Trying to run reduxdevtools with redux saga:

Getting this error:

```
Error
Before running a Saga, you must mount the Saga middleware on the Store using applyMiddleware
```

This is my jscode:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
```

How can I run this devtool with saga? Alternatively what would work otherwise?
[codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3vrvy167p)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've used [redux-devtools-extension package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-devtools-extension) as described here, [redux-devtools-extension documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm).

After adding the package, I've replaced the store definition with this:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  )
);
```

[Fixed Codepen Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vy5p8krl5l)

Comment: Here is the fixed Codepen link. https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-example-63jj6

Comment: the library has been moved to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-devtools/extension

Comment: How can I use this with redux toolkit and redux saga?

Answer (score 11):

The previous answer (by trkaplan) uses an imported method composeWithDevTools from 'redux-devtools-extension' package. 
 If you don't want to install this package, you may use this code (based on [the docs](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#12-advanced-store-setup)):

```js
      const composeEnhancers =  typeof window === 'object' && window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__'] ? 
      window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__']({ }) : compose;
      const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, sagaMiddleware, /*other middleware*/),
        /* other store enhancers if any */
      );
      const emptyReducer = () => {};
      const store = createStore(emptyReducer, enhancer);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you configure your redux, redux-devtool-extension and redux-saga for the real projects..

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import rootSaga from '../sagas';

const configureStore = () => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    return {
        ...createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))),
        runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga),
    };
};

export default configureStore;
```

Comment: what is runSaga ?

Comment: @Rhubarb65 The runSaga function allows starting sagas outside the Redux middleware environment. It also allows you to hook up to external input/output, other than store actions.

Comment: and where are the enhancers?

Answer (score 1):

Incase Compose of Redux is used. Then below code is useful.
Step 1: Add chrome Redux DevTools extension.
step 2: npm install redux-devtools-extension.

```
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
    const store = createStore(
                  reducer,
                  compose(
                  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
                  composeWithDevTools(),
                  ),
                  );
```

Comment: this looked promising for me, as I wanted to pass the Enhancers, but unfortunately my app doesn't work if I do